# How to make a "True Transparent" window to cursor, preferably on a pure QML? (Qt 5.7)

Tags: c++, qt, qml, transparent, qtquick2

["True Transparency" explanation (image, 76kb)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDnBb.jpg).

On that image *ApplicationWindow* have a visually transparent layer. But in fact, cursor does not go to the window behind *ApplicationWindow* (in this case - QT Creator).

"True Transparency" is achieved if add (uncomment) "Qt.WindowTransparentForInput" flag, but the buttons are no longer available (it's are obvious, I know).

I have tried a various flags with similar meanings (from the documentation), but did not find a working combination - cursor are stayind in "default" state when it is within borders of the window (must be in "text" state, because that are text below it).

Did somebody faced with a similar problem, and are you find a solution? Thanks!

Code from image, other project files stayed untouched (Qt Quick Controls 2 Application):

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 240
    x: 400
    y: 210
    color: "transparent"
    flags: Qt.Widget | Qt.FramelessWindowHint //| Qt.WindowTransparentForInput
    //| Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground //| Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground
    //| Qt.WA_NoBackground //| Qt.WA_MouseNoMask

    Button {
        x: ApplicationWindow.width - width
        text: "Right Top Window Corner"
    }
    Button {
        y: ApplicationWindow.height - height
        text: "Left Bottom Window Corner"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you will have to use the operating system APIs to achieve that.

Comment: May be that can be done in another way. What a real target you want to archive?

Comment: Not sure if/how to do what you want in `qml`, but in the `c++` code I think [`QWidget::setMask`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: **ddriver**: if I am not mistaken, these flags are from OS API.

**folibis**: yes, it can be. Real target - pop-up menu with the ability to close on the first click (or button, or an empty space in the window, or outside the window). Logic: if unfocused - hide, if pushed button - hide. Simply add "if clicked an empty space - hide" will resolve that issue, but I try to find the best way.

**G.M.**: QWidget::setMask as I know are more complicated way, and involves image processing (I may be wrong).

Comment: **ddriver**: meant that these flags are more generic for all supported OS APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create a 3 windows, one for the transparent area and one for each of the buttons.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: app
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 240
    x: 400
    y: 210
    color: "transparent"
    flags: Qt.Widget | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowTransparentForInput | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint

    Window {
        visible: true
        flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        x: app.width - width
        height: rightButton.implicitHeight
        Button {
            id: rightButton
            text: "Right Top Window Corner"
        }
    }
    Window {
        visible: true
        flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        y: app.height - height
        height: leftButton.implicitHeight
        Button {
            id: leftButton
            text: "Left Bottom Window Corner"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution are works, and pushed me forward. But creating different window's when buttons can be a lot.. (planned dynamic creation of controls).
I'll wait, and if there is no better option - I will mention that issue resolved. Great thanks!