# QQuickView (QML) transparent for mouse events

Tags: qml, mouseevent, transparent, qquickview

I have a big rectangle with a button centered. I would like that my rectangle is transparent to mouse events except for the button, which must be clickable. I mean, I would like to be able to select code under my rectangle with the mouse, exactly as if no Rectangle was displayed.

I have added a MouseArea for all the big Rect, trying to ignore mouse events, but it does not work.

I read that 'Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents' is used for that purpose, but in Qt windows as fasr as I know, not available in my case.

Thanks in advance

My QML is loaded from main.cpp:

```
   QQuickView* pView = new QQuickView();

    pView->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/MyRect.qml"));
    pView->setFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    pView->setColor("transparent");
    pView->show();
```

MyRect.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Rectangle {
    width: 500
    height: 500

    color: "green" // it would be transparent
    opacity: 0.5

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: 50; width: 50
        onClicked: console.log("clicked");
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        enabled: false
        propagateComposedEvents: true
        hoverEnabled: false

        // All this code I think is useless...
        onClicked: mouse.accepted = false
        onReleased: mouse.accepted = false
        onEntered: mouse.accepted = false
        onExited:  mouse.accepted = false
        onWheel:  mouse.accepted = false
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833624/how-to-make-a-true-transparent-window-to-cursor-preferably-on-a-pure-qml-qt - Appart that the `Rectangle` should be drawn half-transparent, and there is only one `Button` involved

Comment: And what you try to do with this `MouseArea`, I totaly do not get.

Answer (score 0):

The `Rectangle` is transparent to mouse clicks by default.  If you take away that `MouseArea`, the `Button` will receive clicks, and all clicks on the `Rectangle` will pass through to its enclosing parent:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3


ApplicationWindow {
    width: 200; height: 150; visible: true
    property string status;

    ColumnLayout {
      Rectangle {
        width:100;height:100;

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: status = "Enclosing Rectangle Clicked";    
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: 75
            height: 75
            color: "green" // it would be transparent
            opacity: 0.5
            Button {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                height: 25; width: 25
                onClicked: status = "Button clicked";
            }
        }
      }
      Text{ text: status}
    }
}
```

In action:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand when you say "all clicks on the Rectangle will pass through to its enclosing parent", but I suppose it means 'parent' in my application (another part of the same app). In my case I have this standalone window in my application, and I would like that other Windows applications behind my RECT receive the mouse events when clicked in my RECT. Is it possible? Thanks again!!

Comment: Please see the link I posted in the comment under your question. This is a quite similar question. The solution has been, to create multiple windows, one would hold your green `Rectangle` and another on your `Button`. Only the latter handels MouseEvents. Take the example and just add a green `Rectangle` to the top-level `ApplicationWindow`

Comment: @deigo , I think your problem is then that the `QQuickView` itself is catching the mouse click. If you provide a full [S.S.C.C.E.](http://sscce.org/), then perhaps it can be figured out.