# How to create a Qml window so that only a fraction of it cannot be clicked

Tags: qt, qml

I am wondering how to create a Qml window so that only a fraction of it cannot be clicked.

Qt.WindowTransparentForInput works for window, but cannot specify area clickable/unclickable.

[Image for visual explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUrxI.png)

I want to make only red part is clickable.
If you click blue part, notpad under will be clicked.(just like Qt.WindowTransparentForInput flag)

Is It possible in qml?

Comment: You can do the same in Qt or in a different framework?

Comment: @folibis I'm sorry. I have no idea.

Comment: @sqa maybe this approach could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833624/how-to-make-a-true-transparent-window-to-cursor-preferably-on-a-pure-qml-qt